# Jquery not working in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, layout, template

Even I have specified `var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();` in my code but there i am getting the reference error on this line. What may be the possible reasons for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the jquery js file is included in dom. If it is, add this line at the end of the jquery file

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

without `var jQuery =`.
Also make sure the jquery file is included only once.
Clear the cache just in case.
If this doesn't work please explain in details the error you are getting.

Comment: @AkashGoswami. I see that you have a lot of unaccepted answers. Accept the ones that solved your problems.